# Find cells and save information to the left of that cell

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with some 20,000 rows. I have another spreadsheet with around 50 names. The 50 names exist in the sheet with 20,000 rows, and in the column to the left of the name is the information I want.

The spreadsheet looks like the table below (I dont have enough "reputation" to post a picture)

```
987884_R5   Rusescu, Iulian
T1025189_R1 Rusescu, Iulian
T1069036_R1 Pauls, Henrik
T1092840_R1 Pauls, Henrik
T1099343_R2 Pauls, Henrik
857825_R1   Davidsen, Thomas
```

I want to search these 50 names (e.g. "Rusescu, Iulian", "Pauls, Henrik") and save the information to the left of them, but do it all at once instead of using Ctrl+F for every single name. I will have to repeat this task a couple of times with other documents and want to save time.

Can anyone help me? I'm really bad at Excel, but trying to learn it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to repeat this, you should look into VBA.  It would allow you to do exactly what you're looking for without too much trouble.  Take a look at [this article on getting started with VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737.aspx) and see if you're able to create some beginning code.  From there, you can post a new question with what you have tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `987884_R5` is in A2 and you list of names is in ColumnA of Sheet2, copy your long list to a new sheet and in C2 there put:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:A,1,0)
```

and copy down to suit. Filter ColumnC for `#N/A` and delete selected rows. Unfilter and delete Column C.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually this only gives the first instance of info next to a name, I can't really find a way around this, so I'll just leave it here as it might be useful for someone with a sheet of unique names.

So if we call the 20,000 row sheet Sheet1 and the 50 names sheet Sheet2, and assuming the names in Sheet2 are in col A; enter in Sheet2 B1 next to the first name:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MATCH(A1,Sheet1!B:B),0)
```

This will result in the list of 50 names in col A in Sheet 2 having the info associated with those names in col B.